# jQuery reset color pattern every 5 working hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic script below which takes numbers from the field (work hours) in HTML and then matches the pattern. If specific work hours reached 1 hour, the color of HTML text (notes) changes.

My question is how to make the script smaller and the second part is how to reset the color pattern to circle it every 5 hours. So if work hours reached 20 hours, the color pattern should have circled 4 times.

Thank you for your help!

```
        var str = $(".work-hours").text();
        var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
        var match = str.match(pattern);

        if (parseInt(match) == 0) {
            $('.notes').css('color','white');
        }
        if ((parseInt(match) >= 1) && (parseInt(match) < 2)) {
            $('.notes').css('color','green');
        }
        if ((parseInt(match) >= 2) && (parseInt(match) < 3)) {
            $('.notes').css('color','yellow');
        }
        if ((parseInt(match) >= 3) && (parseInt(match) < 4)) {
            $('.notes').css('color','orange');
        }
        if ((parseInt(match) >= 4) && (parseInt(match) < 5)) {
            $('.notes').css('color','pink');
        }
        if (parseInt(match) >= 5) {
            $('.notes').css('color','red');
        }
```

Comment: store an array of strings of colors, and depending on the match just switch to it

Comment: There are 6 colors, not 5. What does " to circle it every 5 hours" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since parseInt makes it floor the value you can simplify the code like this

```js
    var str = $(".work-hours").text();
    var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
    var match = str.match(pattern);
    
    var colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink', 'red'];

    $('.notes').css('color', colors[parseInt(match)]);
```

if you want it to circle around the colors when more hours are added, you could also do some logic on the match to make it fit within the array, or a basic way of extend the array for the extra hours

```js
    var str = $(".work-hours").text();
    var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
    var match = str.match(pattern);
    
    var colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink', 'red'];
    var color = colors[parseInt(match)%colors.length];
    $('.notes').css('color', color);
```

Comment: Only thing this is missing is setInterval with an explanation - then it is a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work only for first 5 hours. The work hours string would accumulate depending on how many hours you worked, so it can stop or add up. setInterval won't work then. But how to make the color change to white when you reached 6 hours?  Or to red when you reached 11?

Comment: because there are 6 colors its not going to end on red at 20, but red on 23

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, you can use `setInterval` function to run any function according to the specific time interval.

```
function changeColor()
{
    ...
}

setInterval(changeColor, 5*60*60*1000); //Works every five hours
```

Answer (score 0):

To help answer your first question, since your if statements are only one line you do not need brackets.

To answer your second question, use the mod symbol, `%` instead of equal sign.

```
    var str = $(".work-hours").text();
    var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
    var match = str.match(pattern);

    if (parseInt(match)%5 === 0) 
        $('.notes').css('color','green');
    if (parseInt(match)%5 === 1)
        $('.notes').css('color','yellow');
    if (parseInt(match)%5 === 2) 
        $('.notes').css('color','orange');
    if (parseInt(match)%5 === 3) 
        $('.notes').css('color','pink');
    if (parseInt(match)%5 === 4)
        $('.notes').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

- The squence of almost identical if statements can be written as a lookup array map.
- Since your regular expression only extracts integers and the conditions are a complete order of integers, you don't need `>=`.
- A curcular selection can be achieved by the modulo operator `%`.

The above applicated to your code, it transforms into:

```
colors = ['white', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink', 'red'] ;
$('.notes').css('color',colors[$(".work-hours").text()
           .match(/[0-9]+/)[0] % colors.length]);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).